# How to work on a fork in GitHub

Tags: php, github, zend-framework2, composer-php

I would like to update a repo in GitHub to make it compatible with ZF3, I have forked the repository to my account and made some updates.

This is my fork: https://github.com/chateaux/zf-oauth2-doctrine

Now to include this in my code base I am using Composer:

```
 {
    "name": "My Project",
    "description": "",
    "license": "PRIVATE - ",
    "keywords": [
        ""
    ],
    "homepage": "",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/chateaux/zf-oauth2-doctrine"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "~0.8",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
        "zf-commons/zfc-rbac":"^2.5",
        "rwoverdijk/assetmanager": "^1.4",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility": "^1.0",
        "zfr/zfr-cors": "^1.2",
        "hounddog/doctrine-data-fixture-module": "^0.0.4",
        "zfcampus/zf-oauth2-client": "dev-master",
        "api-skeletons/zf-oauth2-doctrine": "dev-master",
        "api-skeletons/zf-oauth2-doctrine-console": "^1.1",
        "chateaux/toolbox" : "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "~2.0",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

However when I run a composer update, it appears to be pulling from a cache so I am not getting my updated code base:

```
$ php composer.phar update
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                               
  - Installing zfcampus/zf-oauth2-doctrine (1.0.3)
    Loading from cache
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your custom fork of the repository to the repositories array in your `composer.json` file and add a type field `git` and then point to the branch you want to use with `dev-[branchname]` (for example `patch-4` becomes `dev-patch4`):

```
{
    "name": "My ZF2 application",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/chateaux/zf-oauth2-doctrine.git"
        },
    ],
    "require": {
        ...
        "zfcampus/zf-oauth2-doctrine": "dev-patch-4",
        ...
    }
}
```

Make sure that `patch-4` is an existing branch in your custom repository.

You can find more information on this solution [on the first hit from Google](https://www.google.se/webhp?#q=use%20github%20branch%20composer.json).